# Why my external drive turned in read only mode?

Tags: debian, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure, ext3, read-only

I have this HDD (quite new, 4 months old) which I formatted to ext3 (my router supports ext3, not ext4) and I started copying all my data from an older drive on it (1TB data).

After a bit (a lot of time, it copied 65% of data at least), I've got an error and turned the file system in read-only mode.

What's causing the issue? Here is the dmesg output (sdd1 - /mnt/mymedia):

```
sdd: sdd1
sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page present
sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
ses 8:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page present
sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
 sdd:
kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
EXT3-fs (sdd1): using internal journal
EXT3-fs (sdd1): mounted filesystem with writeback data mode
usb 4-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Unhandled error code
sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd]  
Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: 
Write(10): 2a 00 19 62 65 b4 00 00 1e 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 3407031712
Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 425878708
lost page write due to I/O error on sdd1
Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 425878709
lost page write due to I/O error on sdd1
Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 425878710
lost page write due to I/O error on sdd1
Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 425878711
lost page write due to I/O error on sdd1
Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 425878712
lost page write due to I/O error on sdd1
Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 425878713
lost page write due to I/O error on sdd1
Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 425878714
lost page write due to I/O error on sdd1
Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 425878715
lost page write due to I/O error on sdd1
Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 425878716
lost page write due to I/O error on sdd1
Buffer I/O error on device sdd1, logical block 425878717
lost page write due to I/O error on sdd1
sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Unhandled error code
sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd]  
Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: 
Write(10): 2a 00 19 62 65 d2 00 00 1e 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 3407031952
Aborting journal on device sdd1.
EXT3-fs (sdd1): error in ext3_new_blocks: Journal has aborted
JBD: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sdd1.
EXT3-fs (sdd1): I/O error while writing superblock
EXT3-fs (sdd1): error: ext3_journal_start_sb: Detected aborted journal
EXT3-fs (sdd1): error: remounting filesystem read-only
EXT3-fs (sdd1): error in ext3_orphan_add: Journal has aborted
usb 4-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
usb 4-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=1140
usb 4-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
usb 4-1.2: Product: My Book 1140
usb 4-1.2: Manufacturer: Western Digital
usb 4-1.2: SerialNumber: 574D43315433333236383738
scsi9 : usb-storage 4-1.2:1.0
scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Book 1140     1022 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
scsi 9:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1022 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
ses 9:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
ses 9:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 13
sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page present
sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page present
sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
 sde: sde1
sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page present
sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
EXT3-fs error (device sdd1): ext3_find_entry: reading directory #2 offset 0
usb 4-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 5
usb 4-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
usb 4-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=1140
usb 4-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
usb 4-1.2: Product: My Book 1140
usb 4-1.2: Manufacturer: Western Digital
usb 4-1.2: SerialNumber: 574D43315433333236383738
scsi10 : usb-storage 4-1.2:1.0
scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Book 1140     1022 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
scsi 10:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1022 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
ses 10:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
ses 10:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 13
sd 10:0:0:0: [sde] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 10:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
sd 10:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
sd 10:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page present
sd 10:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 10:0:0:0: [sde] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 10:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page present
sd 10:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
 sde: sde1
sd 10:0:0:0: [sde] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 10:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page present
sd 10:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 10:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
usb 4-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
usb 4-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
usb 4-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=1140
usb 4-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
usb 4-1.2: Product: My Book 1140
usb 4-1.2: Manufacturer: Western Digital
usb 4-1.2: SerialNumber: 574D43315433333236383738
scsi11 : usb-storage 4-1.2:1.0
scsi 11:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Book 1140     1022 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
scsi 11:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1022 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
sd 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
ses 11:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
ses 11:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 13
sd 11:0:0:0: [sde] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 11:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
sd 11:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
sd 11:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page present
sd 11:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 11:0:0:0: [sde] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 11:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page present
sd 11:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
 sde: sde1
sd 11:0:0:0: [sde] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 11:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page present
sd 11:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 11:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
EXT3-fs (sdd1): error: ext3_put_super: Couldn't clean up the journal
usb 4-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 7
usb 3-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
usb 4-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
usb 4-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=1140
usb 4-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
usb 4-1.2: Product: My Book 1140
usb 4-1.2: Manufacturer: Western Digital
usb 4-1.2: SerialNumber: 574D43315433333236383738
scsi12 : usb-storage 4-1.2:1.0
scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Book 1140     1022 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
scsi 12:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1022 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
ses 12:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
ses 12:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 13
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
 sdc: sdc1
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
usb 4-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 8
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc]  
Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
Write(10): 2a 00 06 87 82 a6 00 00 1e 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 876352816
quiet_error: 50 callbacks suppressed
Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 109543846
lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 109543847
lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 109543848
lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 109543849
lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 109543850
lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 109543851
lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 109543852
lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 109543853
lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 109543854
lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 109543855
lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc]  
Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
Write(10): 2a 00 06 87 82 c4 00 00 1e 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 876353056
usb 4-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
usb 4-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=1140
usb 4-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
usb 4-1.2: Product: My Book 1140
usb 4-1.2: Manufacturer: Western Digital
usb 4-1.2: SerialNumber: 574D43315433333236383738
scsi13 : usb-storage 4-1.2:1.0
scsi 13:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Book 1140     1022 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
scsi 13:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1022 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
sd 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
ses 13:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
ses 13:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 13
sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
 sdc: sdc1
sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
usb 4-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 9
```

Should I start an RMA or it's just an Ext3 bug or something like that? Notice that I've done a firmware upgrade before starting copying files (the firmware upgrade was ok anyway).

The Hard Disk is a **Western Digital My Book**

The files were copied through cp -uR

Comment: Is the drive connected via USB to the router?  It looks like the router is losing the USB connection.  Not sure if this is due to the router, the drive, or hardware or software.  First step I'd take to isolating the issue is trying to use the drive on another linux system and see if it stays online or not.

Comment: No while I was performing the test, I was on a Debian distro on my laptop, so a "normal" computer, connected through USB. I can't connect through sata because it's a boxed HDD (can't remove from it). I'm running some testing softwares, a lot of them stuck at some point so I imagine the drive it's actually faulty (the 4th in a month... I have no idea how to buy a working drive now).

Comment: Looking at the log, there's nothing to suggest this is a software or an ext3 issue . . . the drive seems to go offline, so either faulty USB, bad power, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also agree with you, I'll let you know in some days, when tests will finish.

Comment: @ernie: Looks like it was an issue with me that didn't use GPT (I used MBR), at least I've run tests for 3 days with HDD Scan, WD DataGuard and Bad-blocks (and HD Tune), bad-blocks discovered "a lot" of bad blocks (from 2tb and over) so I suppose it doesn't support gpt, same for hd tune. HD scan and wd dataguard didn't find any errors. I suppose gpt is not supported everywhere. Maybe bad-blocks work better if you have debian unstable.

Comment: I don't believe that any of those software tools are the same as the Linux environment you were previously testing in.  The logs show the drive "falling off" in linux, which has little to do with the kind of diags that those tools will run . . . real use case testing may yield more interesting info.

Comment: Yea infact I'm re-writing the files I've written before but with a GPT table, I think it will solve the previous issue (I've tested the drive both in windows and linux, tested a lot of softwares). What I understood is that GPT can still create a lot of issues.

Comment: @ernie: Ok looks like actually was just a GPT issue, I reformatted everything, done a lot of tests, wrote a lot of things, read a lot of things. The HDD looks fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a GPT issue.
Basically, not all software support GPT correctly (I'm on Debian Wheezy, hdd had ext3 partition). Expecially, bad-blocks didn't find correctly the bad blocks after the 2 TB limit, so it's not reliable for such a thing (it found like 800 GB bad blocks).

HD Scan works correctly (on windows, this time tested with an ntfs partition), I wrote also the entire hdd with random data and run a read test, which worked correctly.

I've run WD DataGuard which pass all tests (and didn't find bad blocks), basically looks like a living HDD. I can only cross finger and hope it's not a faulty drive in any case.

So, check GPT because is not correctly support by most software (I needed gparted to format it correctly), the KDE Disk utility can't format 3TB drives as GPT (can format 2TB drives as gpt however), you can find it: it's a known bug.